# Force Debian kernel version

Tags: linux, debian, kernel

I need Debian with kernel 2.6.34.8
Is there any way to force Debian with it?

I don't want to install and then compile version I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, with such a specific requirement, you should be aware that any kernels you grab from Debian have been patched. They're not pristine upstream sources.

That said, Debian stable uses 2.6.32.x and wheezy, I believe, will use 3.2.x. So 2.6.34.x was probably never packaged by the Debian kernel team. Checking [snapshot.debian.org's linux-2.6 page](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/linux-2.6/) shows that 2.6.34 was put in experimental, but that appears to be 2.6.34, without the .8. And of course, it contains Debian patches.

I think 2.6.34 has make deb-pkg, so it should be fairly easy to build the upstream source into a `.deb`, and then install that. Your other option would be to grab the Debian sources from the older 2.6.34.0, and merge in .8 yourself. That will lead to a .8 with Debian patches, and is probably a fair bit more work.

BTW: If you're going to run 2.6.34.x, you should run 2.6.34.14 (the current release on that branch).

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing operating systems course and I need exactly 2.6.34.8 kernel version as all of my code would be tested is such environment

Comment: @Ari yeah, then you definitely want to download it from upstream, either their tarball or using git, and compile it yourself.

Comment: It is rather weird that the class uses such an old/strange kernel... if I'd been teaching something like that, I'd be covering either a (recent!) released kernel version for the distribution in use, or one of the latest vanilla kernels.

Comment: @vonbrand Apparently, Wind River is using 2.6.34.x still, and of course they're probably on something newer than .8—they're paying the guy to maintain it, so... (http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1071766)

Comment: @vonbrand Kernel version doesn't really matter, but you need to chose one for course. It easier to choose one, you used before, so they just don't change it every year.

Comment: @Ari, the Linux kernel moves _fast_, to use such an old one does nobody any real favor, IMVHO.