# Debian kernel version for Raspberry with respect to snap

Tags: debian, kernel, snap

I have a Raspberry 4B with Debian 11.2 installed. I could successfully install snapd. Trying to run "snap install core" resulted in an error telling that filesystem "squashfs" is not supported.

The kernel version is "5.4.72-v7l+" (output of "uname -r").

A friend of mine also has a Raspberry 4B. He installed snapd and he could also run successfully "snap install core" and "snap refresh core".
However, the version of his kernel (Debian 11.2) is "5.10.63-v8+".

Both he and me, in our /etc/apt/sources.list file is:

```
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ bullseye main contrib non-free rpi
```

There are some questions:

1. Why do the kernel versions differ?
2. How can I get the latest kernel version (without re-compiling it)? Note that I regularly run "apt-get dist-upgrade -y"
3. How to enable support for squashfs?

When reading the 8-years old post [Force Debian kernel version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70515/force-debian-kernel-version) it was obviously not so easy to force a more recent kernel version. However that post did not help me much.

Any suggestions welcome!

---

@Eduardo

modprobe squashfs results in:

modprobe: FATAL: Module squashfs not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.72-v7l+

NOTE:

1. There is NO directory /lib/modules/5.4.72-v7l+
2. There is directory /lib/modules/4.9.35-v7+
3. find /lib/modules/4.9.35-v7+/kernel -name "*squash*" outputs:

/lib/modules/4.9.35-v7+/kernel/fs/squashfs

/lib/modules/4.9.35-v7+/kernel/fs/squashfs/squashfs.ko

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo modprobe squashfs` first?

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and on again?" - just asking, there is no other way to load the new kernel.

Comment: I deinstalled snapd, rebooted, ran apt-get update && apt-get upgrade and installed snapd again. Same problem. Dieter